# Websphere - How can I change default "Content Type/charset" of Web sphere

Tags: http, character-encoding, http-headers, websphere

When I requested html file, It returned

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=Windows-874
```

Like image below

[image]

I would like to change it to

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I couldn't use `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` because it is html file.

How can I change it in Websphere?

Comment: Which MVC framework are you using?

Comment: How about adding to your html header <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: @Gas I tried it. It's not work

Comment: why aren't you using the jsp extension? otherwise you have to change the mapping of the supported jsp extensions in WebSphere.

Answer (score 0):

In Servlet you can do:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

*`response`  is an `instanceof HttpServletResponse`*

If you are not using an MVC framework but you're using JSP as a controller (*highly discouraged*), then wrap the solution inside `<% %>` at the top of your page.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open the WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi or WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xml file.

add a JSP Attribute

`<jspAttributes xmi:id="JSPAttribute_4" name="jsp.file.extensions" value="*.html"/>`

Restart your application

*else you need to change your .html file to .jsp  to get it to compile